# Cannot boot Huawei Mate D16 from USB Ubuntu stick. Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. My goal is to install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb, live-usb, lts

Hello AskUbuntu community.

**My goal is to install Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS on my Huawei Mate D16 laptop.**

I have bought another M.2 SSD drive and installed it in my laptop.
So currently I have two physical M.2 SSD drives:

1. Fist one is the SSD that the laptop was provided with from the factory - Windows 10,
2. Second is the one I've bought and put inside the laptop myself.

I'm writing this to make it clear I'm not attempting to install Ubuntu on the same drive as Windows 10, which is quite a challenge I assume. **I have a dedicated physical drive only for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.**

I have downloaded Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS ISO and I have flashed it to my USB drive using Balena Etcher software.

Then I've restarted the laptop and entered the BIOS settings, but I couldn't find my USB drive to boot from. I've turned `Secure Boot` off and tried it again to no avail.

```
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Try the new cross-platform PowerShell https://aka.ms/pscore6

PS C:\Windows\system32> Confirm-SecureBootUEFI
False
```

After that I've flashed the USB drive again, but it also changed nothing.
I still wasn't able to see my Ubuntu Desktop installation USB in BIOS settings.

I've found [this](https://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/content/en-us00693076/), which only made me angry.

I guess my Ubuntu installation USB drive is not FAT32 after I've flashed it with Balena Etcher. It's something different, so how can I boot from this USB drive if disabling `Sacure Boot` didn't help??

[image]

Under F12 I can access boot manager and it looks like this:

[image]

Unless I disable booting from both SSD's in my BIOS, to force my Huawei to boot from USB:

**What needs 2 be done to boot this Huawei Mate D16 laptop from Ubuntu flashed USB??**

Comment: According to the link you provided, pressing the F12 button right after pressing the power button to start the laptop should show you some choices, assuming the USB is plugged in before starting the laptop. Take a picture of that screen and add it to your question.

Comment: This looks like something specific to the Huawei Mate D16 laptop's UEFI settings. Or a hardware problem. Neither of which is related to Ubuntu.